# Ant - sf:compileAndTest

Tags: unit-test, ant, deployment

I can't find any documentation for the ant command "sf:compileAndTest", yet I see references to it in several places. [Example.](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12965/how-run-tests-in-default-namespace-for-sandbox-using-ant/12968)

When I try to run it in a ant target I get doodly squat:

```
[sf:compileAndTest] compileAndTest on https://test.salesforce.com, compiling 0 classes and 0 triggers, deleting 0 classes and 0 triggers
```

(This is after a successful deploy, I know there are classes and triggers in the target Org)

Is this ant command supported? Or are we forced to bundle test running with deployment, eg

```
<sf:deploy ------------ runAllTests="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about `sf:compileAndTest` but:

[sf:deploy](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_deploying_ant_deploy.htm) can be used to do a compile and test by using the `checkOnly` attribute. Setting this attribute to true will mean that nothing will get saved to the server.

```
<sf:deploy 
       username="username@username.com" 
       password="password"
       serverurl="https://test.salesforce.com" 
       runAllTests="true" 
       checkOnly="true"/>
```